# Telerik RadComboBox AutomaticLoadOnDemand

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-combobox

I use Telerik RadComboBox in my project. I set `EnableAutomaticLoadOnDemand="true"` on RadComboBox. It works good but when I want to set selected item on load of `page event`, it doesn't show selected item

Comment: To show selected item for Telerik RadComboBox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606197/radcombobox-selected-value-is-empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With load on demand mode, so combobox does not have any item. It just has item(s) when you action on it.

In my opinion, you should get the specific item and add it to combobox manually on page load event like this way (I'm not sure the structure, just an idea.)

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    var itemSelected = service.GetById(Id); //item Id
    this.combobox.Items.Add(new RadComboboxItem(itemSelected.Id, itemSelected.Name));
    this.combobox.SeletedValue = Id.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RadCombo allows to set up SelectedValue and Text properties even through there are no items in it.