# RadComboBox selected value is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, selectedvalue, radcombobox

I get the `SelectedValue = ""` when i click on My button .

**My aspx :**

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddl_contactList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="False"
            CollapseDelay="0" Culture="ar-EG" ExpandDelay="0" Filter="StartsWith" ItemsPerRequest="10"
            MarkFirstMatch="true" Skin="Outlook" EnableAutomaticLoadOnDemand="True" EmptyMessage="-New Menu-"
            ShowMoreResultsBox="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_contactList_SelectedIndexChanged"
            EnableItemCaching="false" EnableLoadOnDemand="True" EnableVirtualScrolling="True">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

---

**My .cs :**

```
 private void BindContactLists(int year, int main_code)
        {
            ddl_contactList.Items.Clear();
            DataTable dt = ContactList.GetContactListsByDep(year, main_code);
            ddl_contactList.DataSource = dt;
            ddl_contactList.DataTextField = "list_desc";
            ddl_contactList.DataValueField = "list_code";
            ddl_contactList.DataBind();

        }
```

---

I call it in the `page load` because when I call it in the
`!Page.Ispostback`, I get the following error:

> There is no assigned data source. Unable to complete callback request.

How can I fix this problem?  Right now:

`ddl_contactList.Text == "MySelectedItemText"`

but

`selectedValue == ""` and `selectedItem == ""`

Comment: Could you provide the class for ContactList too, or at least a sample return from ContactList.GetContactListsByDep(year, main_code)?

Comment: Could you post more of your code here?  Possible the whole load event?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move your call to `BindContactLists()` from the `Page_Load()` method to the `Page_Init()` method. This allows the control to be setup for ViewState binding later in the page lifecycle, and allow proper population of the SelectedValue property.

Answer (score 3):

It's normal because you re-bind your datas => so you erase your selected value

I suggest you to set your block in `!IsPostBack` => you don't erase when you post

In PageLoad

```
if(! IsPostBack)
{

           ddl_contactList.Items.Clear();
            DataTable dt = ContactList.GetContactListsByDep(year, main_code);
            ddl_contactList.DataSource = dt;
            ddl_contactList.DataTextField = "list_desc";
            ddl_contactList.DataValueField = "list_code";
            ddl_contactList.DataBind();


}
```

And you persist your control with `ViewState`

Set `EnableViewState="true"`

Comment: I try this but i get the following error :
`There is no assigned data source. Unable to complete callback request`

Comment: Databound controls aren't entirely stored in ViewState, and the control would not be databound when `IsPostBack` is true.

Answer (score 1):

make sure  your  datasource like dataset or datatable fill  when  page load  or init fire